# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNPushNotification.getInitialNotification')

Tags: react-native, build.gradle

I am getting this error while setting up react native project from GitHub. Please help me to solve this issue. I have installed the node modules and run the command "npm run android". After that, I am facing this error.

```
 TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNPushNotification.getInitialNotification')
```

Comment: Have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352515/react-native-push-notification-is-undefined ?

Comment: Please take a look at this Github issue: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1335 it is the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

For me it was node version. Got this error when using node version 10. Error disappeared when switched to node version 16.